# Newtonsoft serialization of object with few not serializable properties

Tags: c#, serialization, error-handling, json.net

I use the following code to serialize JSON

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    MaxDepth = 10
};
        
string serializationResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentObject, settings);
```

But i have found that if currentObject contains not serializable items it will throw Exception (for example a reference to dirty a DataContext).
I have no control over currentObject because the actual code is part of a logging utility, and so 'currentObject' could be everything the utility user submitted to utility.
I would like to be able to serialize 'currentObject' as much as i can, avoiding problematic properties if there are any.

So i modified the code in the following way :

```
    try
    {
        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
            MaxDepth = 10,
            Error = delegate (object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
            {
                args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
            }
        };

        string serializationResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentObject, settings);

        return serializationResult;
    }
    catch ( Exception err)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

I test it again passing a 'currentObject' in which a property is a dirty DataConetxt, and now the serialization process never end. Seems like it keep looping on the error hanlder.
After an huge amount of times (few minutes) i finally get a serialization error :

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'
   at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.get_Length()
   at GetLength(Object )
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
```

Is not clear to me what i am missin and how to handle such situation in which a property of object to serialize may be not serializable. Is my logic correct but the prolem is that DataContext is huge to serialize (and if so i have to try to filter out such situation)?
Or i mistakenly impelemented the error handling?

Comment: Your error-handling implementation is correct. But it might be a bug on `Newtonsoft` side. It seems it tries to serialize a property with a getter throwing `NotImplementedException` but this exception is leaking away from the serialization handler. Try upgrading your newton soft version.

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YzmaK5) that replicates your issue. But in this version uncommenting the error handler makes it works as expected.

Comment: @Eldar it's strange i am using versione 13.0.0.1 for the Net Framework 4.8. Isn't it the latest stable? Maybe the datacontext has so many not serializable properties that it seem looping but instead it's only extremely slow? If so can i place a timeout per property?

Comment: Yeap it's the latest stable and my fiddle was using the same version. You may not set a timeout per property. But instead, you can use reflection to get the properties of the object and do the serialization in a `Task` for each property, so you can set a timeout for each task.

Comment: @Eldar testing properties and discarding invalid object seems a bit time consuming, but still a viable solution. I submitted the code i am using. Let me know if you spot some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Even if not clear exactly where is the issue with DataContext, it's seems reasoneable to me that try to serialize such a complex object is not a good approach (unmanaged resource may be involved behind the hood).

As suggested by @Eidat i tried to create a test method to check if the serialization of an entry/property works in a given amount of time or if it fail.
If the serailization failed then skip the entity/property.

This approach may be a bit too time consuming, but if performance is not a top prioritiy, or volume of data are low, this solution may be viable.

To do so in a resuable way i write that simple extension method on which i test the "critical" object before serialization (with critical i mean object i don't know where they came from, and for that reason they may be not serializable).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if an object is serializable throught Newtonsoft serialization in a given amount of time
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="this">The object to test</param>
    /// <param name="settings">The settings to use for serialization (optional)</param>
    /// <param name="timeoutMs">The timeout in millisenconds, in which the test have to complete (optional : default 97ms)</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsNSSerializable ( this object @this, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null, int timeoutMs = 97)
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan testTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMs);
            var currentSettings = settings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                MaxDepth = 10
            };

            using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(testTimeout))
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                var token = tokenSource.Token;
                Thread workerThread = null;

                Task testActivity = Task.Run(() => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        workerThread = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(@this, settings);
                            }
                            catch (Exception err)
                            { }
                        });

                        workerThread.Join(testTimeout);
                    } 
                    catch (Exception err) 
                    { } 
                } , token);
                
                if (!testActivity.Wait(testTimeout))
                {
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    global::System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

                    if (workerThread != null && workerThread.IsAlive)
                        workerThread.Abort();
                }

                return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```